# Different Java Scanner for input of different types

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Imagine the following scanario: 
I have a program which ask for an integer input, followed by a String input.

```
int age=0;
String name;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter Age: ");
age = sc.nextInt();
System.out.print("Enter Name: ");
name= sc.nextLine();
```

With the aobe codes, I was not given a chance to enter the name. So normally I will declare 2 scanner objects as follows:

```
int age=0;
String name;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);    //2nd Scanner object

System.out.print("Enter Age: ");
age = sc.nextInt();
System.out.print("Enter Name: ");
name= sc2.nextLine();                    //Using 2nd Scanner Object
```

**My question is:** Is it necessary to declare multiple scanner objects to accept inputs of different types?? Am I doing the proper way as aobve?

I have this question in mind for years already. (Several questions in SO mention multiple scanner, but their questions only used one scanner object, so I am asking this today.)

Comment: reading your coment below, have you tried reading name 1st and after reading age?

Comment: @Frakcool If we read string before reading int, it will work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@skiwi is right about only using one `Scanner`, so you're doing that right. The reason it doesn't work is that `nextInt()` consumes all characters that make up the integer, but it does not touch the end-of-line character. So when `nextLine()` is called, it sees that there are no characters before the end-of-line character, so it thinks that an empty line was entered, and you get an empty String back. However, `nextLine()` does consume the end-of-line character, so if you call `sc.nextLine();` once before you do `name = sc.nextLine();`, it should work.

Answer (score 3):

You were not given a chance to enter the name because `nextInt()` doesn't read the new-line character `'\n'` (inputted by user after pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>), whereas `nextLine()` does. So as soon as you call `name = sc.nextLine();`, it will just read the `'\n'` character that the `nextInt()` didn't read already.

Definitely do not create a new Scanner if the Scanner if you're scanning the same thing (like `System.in`) - only change Scanners if you are scanning something else, like different files or something.

To get your code working (with only one Scanner instance), use this:

```
int age = 0;
String name;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter Age: ");
age = sc.nextInt();
System.out.print("Enter Name: ");

sc.nextLine(); // "dispose" of the '\n' character
               // so that it is not recorded by the next line

name = sc.nextLine();

// print your findings
System.out.println("------\nAge: " + age + "\nName: " + name);
```

Example input/output:

```
Enter Age: 17
Enter Name: Michael
------
Age: 17
Name: Michael
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use only one `Scanner` instance per object that you are scanning. In this case you are reading from the `System.in`, so opening two scanners on the same them concurrently does not even make sense.

So you definately want to go with your first option, then the question comes, what is wrong with it:

Well, you ask for `sc.nextInt()`, an integer, and a name rarely is an integer. You are most likely looking for either `name = sc.next()` for one word or for `name = sc.nextLine()` for a whole sentence (until the enter key has been pressed).

Also be aware that after `sc.nextInt()`, actually after any `sc.next***()`, you **need** to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I have edited it. The problem is that, after the first input of integer, user will not be given a chance to enter the name.

Comment: The problem does not lies with my typo error earlier. When we use a similar scanner object to scan for inputs of different types, problems do occur.

Comment: @user3437460 Updated the answer, did you press enter after inputting?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
name = sc.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

This must work perfectly. I tested it out.

```
int age=0;
String name;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter Age: ");
age = sc.nextInt();
System.out.print("Enter Name: ");
name= sc.nextLine();
```

Comment: Hmm, I am not asking for codes nor work-around solutions. But of course over the years, I already knew there should only exist one Scanner object which does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

why this code has not work?

```
package Programs;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class LibraryManagement {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String Sname, Bname, Bauthor;
    int Sid,Sclass,Bid;
    void StudInfo()
    {
    
    System.out.print("Enter the Student Id: ");
    Sid=s.nextInt();
    
    System.out.print("Enter the Student name: ");
    Sname=s.nextLine();
    
    System.out.print("Enter the Student Class: ");
    Sclass=s.nextInt();
    
    System.out.println("Student detail is saved:  \n Id : "+ Sid + " Name : "+ Sname+ " Class : ");
    
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          LibraryManagement obj= new LibraryManagement();
          obj.StudInfo();
        }
    
    }
```

output is :
Enter the Student Id: 10 
Enter the Student name: Enter the Student Class:

Comment: The accepted answer mentions that you need to .readLine() once after the .readInt() to consume the newline character that comes after the number string. The code you are posting here suffers from the problem the OP is asking in the question because it never awaits for the user to enter the name of the student as shown even in the output you show below. i would advise to  delete this answer if that's ok with you.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30843764)

Answer (score 0):

You can understand this by the further example. A single scanner class cannot be declared for taking inputs of different datatypes. So be specific while taking inputs in Java. If you are going to take multiple string inputs then make a particular scanner class for it and if you are going to take like multiple inputs for int then make a specific scanner class for it & it depends on different datatypes & if you want to take input in char then make a particular scanner class for it as well. It will help us reduce writing more code so if you are taking like 10 int inputs then make a specific scanner class for it and use these single scanner class names for 10 inputs basically it will reduce us writing 9 lines of more code for each int input, if you are taking 10 string inputs then make a particular scanner class for it & if you are going to take 10 character inputs then make a particular scanner class for it AND SO ON  .........:) This will reduce writing code for each type of input.

> **Code**

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.lang.*;
    import java.io.*;

    public class arraylistExample {
        public static void main(String[]args){
            // This is a common scanner class for string type of inputs 
            Scanner stringcommonforall=new Scanner(System.in);
            // This is a common scanner class for integer type of inputs 
            Scanner intcommonforall=new Scanner(System.in);
            int size;
            int pos=0;
            boolean findornot=false;
            String found;
            ArrayList<String> name=new ArrayList<String>();
            System.out.print("Enter the size of the ArrayList >> ");
            size=intcommonforall.nextInt();
            // when your are using one scanner for all types of input then you will get the error 
            for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
                System.out.print(">> ");
                name.add(stringcommonforall.nextLine());
            }
            System.out.print("Enter the element you want to search inside the arraylist >> ");
            found=stringcommonforall.nextLine();
            for(String i:name){
                if(i.equals(found)){
                    findornot=true;
                    pos=name.indexOf(found);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(findornot==true){
                System.out.println("The elements inside he arraylist >> "+name);
                System.out.println("The element >> "+found+" is found at the positioin >> "+pos);
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("The elements inside he arraylist >> "+name);
                System.out.println("The element >> "+found+" is not found inside the arraylist ");
            }
        }
    }
```

> **Output**

```
    Enter the size of the arraylist >> 5
    >> lorem ipsum
    >> xyz
    >> zyx 1
    >> june
    >> done
    Enter the element you want to search inside the arraylist >> done
    The elements inside he arraylist >> [lorem ipsum, xyz, zyx 1, june, done]
    The element >> done is found at the positioin >> 4
```