# How to use the Scanner class properly?

Tags: java

I'm doing an assignment for class. For some reason the program completely skips the part where the variable `name` is supposed to be typed in by the user. I can't think of any reason why it's behaving this way, since the rest of my code that is after the `cardType` part (which asks for things such as `String` and `int` types work fine and in order.

```
        System.out.println("Enter the card information for wallet #" + 
                                    (n+1) + ":\n---\n");
        System.out.println("Enter your name:");
        String name = scan.nextLine();
        name = capitalOf(name);
        System.out.println("Enter card type");
        String cardType = scan.nextLine();
        cardType = capitalOf(cardType);
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code in your debugger? If so, what do you see?

Comment: If you have a call to `nextInt()` or `nextDouble()` in your code, call `nextLine()` (and ignore the contents) before your next call to `nextLine()` .

Comment: How is scanner used before this line?

Comment: I would like to add one more though its not relevant to the question asked. if your method capitalOf(name) converts string to capital. I would recomend  you to use the inbuilt method toUpper defined in String class(if your prof allows it).

Comment: This question has actually been raised many times by different users. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542833/different-java-scanner-for-input-of-different-types

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to consume the end of the last line you read prior to trying to get the user name :

```
    scan.nextLine(); // add this
    System.out.println("Enter the card information for wallet #" + 
                                (n+1) + ":\n---\n");
    System.out.println("Enter your name:");
    String name = scan.nextLine();
    name = capitalOf(name);
    System.out.println("Enter card type");
    String cardType = scan.nextLine();
    cardType = capitalOf(cardType);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is behaving this way because I am quite sure you used the same scanner object to scan for integers/double values before you used it to scan for name.

Having said that does not mean you have to create multiple scanner objects. (You should never do that).

One simple way to over come this problem is by scanning for strings even if you are expecting integers/doubles and cast it back.

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
int numbers = scn.nextInt();  //If you do this, and it skips the next input
scn.nextLine();  //do this to prevent skipping 

//I prefer this way
int numbers = Integer.toString(scn.nextLine());
String str = scn.nextLine();    //No more problems
```