# Java Scanner nextLine method

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I understand that using the nextInt() method does not consume the new line character so to deal with that I need to use an empty nextLine() method to move on.

My question is, as an alternative solution would a program be open to any sort of run-time errors to use two scanners, one for string input and one for integers?

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner ints = new Scanner(System.in);

int userInt = ints.nextInt();
String userInput = in.nextLine();
```

Thanks for any help!

(edited so the question is less subjective)

Comment: try nextLine() only and parse the number using Integer.parseInt()

Comment: @JimmyPage I don't think that was his question.

Comment: You could probably take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542833/different-java-scanner-for-input-of-different-types

Comment: @Tacocat right...thanks

Comment: @KaiWuToh thanks for the link - the second answer from skiwi is helpful, although the code above works, so why does he suggest you should only use one Scanner instance per object you are scanning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is

```
String userInt = ints.nextInt();
```

You are inputting an int value into a string value
try

```
String userInt=ints.next();
//OR
int userInt=ints.nextInt();
```

getting back to your question
**no it isnt "bad" to have two scanners it is just not required.**

Comment: sorry! typo! that should be int userInt - fixed in the original post, thanks. if you were teaching this, would you teach it one way over the other (two scanners for different inputs vs. one scanner using empty nextLine() method)?

Comment: Sure. Although could you mark my answer as a tick(if it answered your question)?
1) you do not require two scanners in a class unless youre doing something exceptional.
2) one scanner can be used for your case 

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

int userInt = in.nextInt();
String userInput = in.nextLine(); or you can use in.next() instead of nextLine

Comment: OK Thanks for the help!